# Curly braces with LCtrl+LShift+LAlt+è - how?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, keyboard, linux-mint, keymap

I'm using Linux Mint 15 x64, and I want to add a new key mapping for curly braces. I'm using italian keyboard layout. On Windows I'm used to creating curly braces by pressing

```
(Left Ctrl && Left Shift && Left Alt) && (è || +)
```

By <kbd>è</kbd> and <kbd>+</kbd> I mean the two keys to the right of the <kbd>P</kbd> key, those that create square brackets when only <kbd>Left Shift</kbd> is down.

How can I enable curly braces creation as I'm used to on Windows?

Comment: Do you mean creating your own shortcut? There is this link about it [link creating shortcuts](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/356)

Comment: @AndreaGottardi: no, I don't want to launch a program with a shortcut. I want to be able to type curly braces ('{' and '}') by pressing the LCtrl+LShift+LAlt+'è' combination, which works on Windows, but not on Linux.

Comment: did you already try `loadkeys`?

Comment: @AndreaGottardi: I tried manually changing keyboard mappings, but I couldn't find a way to express the key combination I want. Loadkeys looks like what I tried - I need help figuring out the right command to express the LCtrl+LShift+LAlt+'è' combination.

Comment: try `loadkeys it`, if you didn't.

Comment: maybe it has some more information [configuring keyboards](http://wiki.linuxquestions.org/wiki/Configuring_keyboards)

Comment: @AndreaGottardi: I don't know what command I should type, and googling didn't help. Any pointer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unique reliable solution I found, that supports the exact key bind I want, is to use Autokey.
I created two phrases, one for '{' and one for '}'.

It works perfectly. The only annoying thing is that I have to start Autokey before coding.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that [xbindkeys](http://www.nongnu.org/xbindkeys/) and [xte](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xte) are what you're looking for. There is [a question over on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/254424/how-can-i-change-what-keys-on-my-keyboard-do-how-can-i-create-custom-keyboard/254425#254425) that will walk you through setting up the bindings. Consider copying and pasting the curly braces, "{" and "}", from a web page or some such if you can't type them directly into the binding command.

Comment: Seems a good solution, but I can't find the name for the '{' key.
"xte 'key {'" doesn't work

Comment: Couldn't get it to work, apparently '{' is minus+parensleft, but it doesn't seem to work properly with xte keyup/keydown

Comment: I can't try this out until I get home, but does "xte 'key \{'" work? This is a long shot, but does "xte 'str {'" work? Again, I'll test at home tonight and update my answer.

Comment: Surprisingly, it's "xte 'str {'" and "xte 'str }'" that work.

Comment: "xte 'str {'" works, but the whole xbindkeys system isn't really reliable. I get different combinations pressing the same keys with xbindkeys -k and I couldn't just get it to work reliably. Any other idea?

Comment: I'll post a new answer, but it isn't something I've tried at all.

Answer (score 1):

As in my other answer, I'm pretty much just pointing you to the [AskUbuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/a/257497/44179).

The answer about Xmodmap sounds like it's more reliable than xbindkeys and xte.

You can use [XKeyCaps](http://www.jwz.org/xkeycaps/) as a GUI (I haven't tried yet), but it looks really old.

It looks like Xmodmap may not be able to handle <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>, but [it should be able to handle either <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xmodmap#Keymap_table).

Answer (score -1):

just had this problem myself, tried all solutions here to no avail.
noticed looking at my keyboard that the parenthesis key is only used when shift is pressed - if shift is not pressed it just uses normal brackets, so I tried: "xte 'str ]'" and it works perfectly, I hope this helps somebody.

Comment: This does not answer the author's question.  Edit your answer so it directly and in detail answers the author's question.  Comments should never be submitted as an answer to a question