# How can I simulate pressing `{` with xte?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

How can I signal a `{` using ste? I have tried the following but none of these seem to work:

```bsh
xte 'key {'    # Outputs: Unable to resolve keysym for '{'
xte 'key \{'   # Outputs: Unable to resolve keysym for '\{'
xte 'str {'    # Outputs: 7
xte 'str \{'   # Outputs -7
xte "str {"    # Outputs: 7
```

I have the same problem with `}`, `[` and `]`.

---

UPDATE: I found this [post](https://superuser.com/a/598118/1087113) where somebody referenced this same issue. It is still unclear to me how they solved it though.

---

UPDATE 2: I found out [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/692516/864191) that you can also use ASCII codes. Unfortunately, it didn't work for `{`:

```bsh
xte 'key 0x7b' # Outputs: [
```

---

UPDATE 3: Extra information required to debug the problem:

Output of `$ xmodmap`:

```
xmodmap:  up to 4 keys per modifier, (keycodes in parentheses):

shift       Shift_L (0x32),  Shift_R (0x3e)
lock
control     Control_L (0x25),  Control_R (0x69)
mod1        Alt_L (0x40),  Alt_R (0x6c),  Meta_L (0xcd)
mod2        Num_Lock (0x4d)
mod3
mod4        Super_L (0x85),  Super_R (0x86),  Super_L (0xce),  Hyper_L (0xcf)
mod5        ISO_Level3_Shift (0x5c),  Mode_switch (0xcb)
```

Keyboard layout: United States-International

[image: United States-International keyboard layout]

Comment: Whoever downvoted the question, could you please let me know what is wrong with the question? I find it mean just downvoting a question instead of commenting on what you think is wrong with it. I'm sure you can see that this is the first time I am asking a question around here.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but you mention `ste` in the title in the first part, and then go on using `xte` ... (BTW, you can edit your question).

Comment: Oh wow, now this is what I meant. Fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### First approach

Look up the X keysyms. You can find them using `xev` and pressing the keys you are interested it, `xmodmap -pke` to print out your current table, or have a look at `/usr/include/X11/XF86keysym.h`.

Using one of these, you'll find that the keysym for `{` is `braceleft`.

However, there's a gotcha: `key`, `keydown`, and `keyup` produce actual key presses. If on your keyboard, like on my keyboard, the braces need the shift key, you need to press this as well:

```
xte 'keydown Shift_L' 'key braceleft' 'keyup Shift_L'
```

produces `{` on my machine.

### Second approach

Don't both with keysyms, use `xte str` instead:

```
xte 'str {'
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Your first approach works on my machine too. Your second approach, however, produces a `7` (as shown in the question). Any idea why?

Comment: You may have language settings for some keyboard layout where interesting things happen. But I can't debug this remotely, I'd need at least to see the complete `xmodmap` output, and there are other things in the `XKBD` extension that could cause this, and potentially dozens of files to look at if this is the case. But at least edit the question and explain which keyboard layout you use, and where the `{` is.

Comment: Changing the **Input Source** inside the **Region & Language** settings from __English (US)__ to __English (US, alt. intl.)__ made the second approach you proposed work as well. Thanks again.

Comment: After I rebooted my computer I had issues again. What finally solved the problem was removing all **Input Source** except **English (US)**. Previously, I had a **Spanish** keyboard layout option in the list.

Comment: Then guess: `xte` happened to use the Spanish keyboard layout to get the keypress/keyrelease events necessary for `{`, because it couldn't detect that this wasn't active, and English(US) was active instead. If Spanish is anything like German, then Alt-Gr 7 likely produces the `{`, and this sequence of keys on the English(US) layout gives you `7` instead.